# form is uploading to /tmp/phpHQ6U5X instead of newly set /var/www/html/upload_tmp

Tags: php

I am trying to upload files to my server through a CRUD. I am having an issue moving the uploaded file to its new directory which exists.

I am receiving this warning..

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(../images/me.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/admin/addpicture.php
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpHQ6U5X' to '../images/me.png'
```

Realizing this might be a permission issue with /tmp, I decided to change the temporary upload folder.

I set a temporary upload folder in the php.ini file I found listed in phpinfo()

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php/7.0/apache2
```

I restarted my server using

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

I checked to make sure my changes were set with phpinfo() again

```
upload_tmp_dir  /var/www/html/upload_tmp
```

Also, I checked to see if my basedir is set

```
open_basedir    no value
```

I tried to upload the file again

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpHQ6U5X' to '../images/me.png'
```

I am including code for completeness but I can confirm that this code works for me on localhost and other servers I have worked on.

PHP

```
if(isset($_FILES) & !empty($_FILES)){
  $name = $_FILES['pictureimage']['name'];
  $size = $_FILES['pictureimage']['size'];
  $type = $_FILES['pictureimage']['type'];
  $tmp_name = $_FILES['pictureimage']['tmp_name'];
  $max_size = 10000000;
  $extension = substr($name, strpos($name, '.') + 1);

  if(isset($name) && !empty($name)){
    if($size<=$max_size){
      $location = '../images/';
      $filepath = $location.$name;
      if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $filepath)){
```

HTML

```
<input type="file" name="pictureimage" id="pictureimage">
```

What am I missing? Why would the form continue to upload to /tmp instead of the upload_tmp_dir that I set?

Comment: The problem is not the source directory, it's the target directory. Please check with `file_exists()`, `is_writable()`, `is_dir()` and `realpath()` that the target directory is valid, exists, is writable and the correct path.

Comment: Thank you that got me to the next step in debugging. Files are now uploading after setting the owner to www-data after confirming it was not writeable. Out of curiosities sake, any idea why it might be continuing to write to /tmp? This is solved for me as far as I am concerned so if you make it an answer I'll mark it and close it.

Comment: `/tmp` is the default setting for [`upload_tmp_dir`](https://www.php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir)

Comment: Thank you, @Phil. I am aware of that. The question was why is it ignoring the change I made.

Comment: How did you verify the change? Is your `phpinfo()` output in the browser or CLI? Keep in mind, the CLI and web module / FastCGI can use different config files

Comment: @Progman - Though I still don't know why my server is uploading to the default upload folder after making a change. The actual problem I was having was solved thanks to your input and you should receive rep for it, if you would care to turn your comment into an answer I will close it.

Comment: @Phil I checked using phpinfo().

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. CLI or browser?

Comment: Browser. I am researching fastcgi now.. was not aware of these modes.